# JNI: Unknown signature for type 'class'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

So I have an app that is built for android using unity that needs to scedual a function to run using the same proccess that notifications do but when i actually run it i get the error
`JNI: Unknown signature for type 'AlarmReciver'`

the code that is called when i get this error is

```
public class AlarmManagerHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AlarmManagerHelper Instance;

    private void Start()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    // Method to schedule an alarm
    public void ScheduleAlarm(float delayInSeconds, Action action)
    {
        long triggerTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(delayInSeconds).Ticks / 10000; // Convert delay to milliseconds
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new         AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaClass alarmClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.app.AlarmManager");
        AndroidJavaObject alarmManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "alarm");

        AndroidJavaObject alarmIntent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", currentActivity, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
    alarmIntent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", "Server_Managment_Background_Processes"); // "YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION" is the unique identifier like the notification id in scqeduling notifications so a good value would be something like "Function Call 1" or something

        int requestCode = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, int.MaxValue);
        AndroidJavaObject pendingIntentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.app.PendingIntent");
        AndroidJavaObject pendingIntent = pendingIntentClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getBroadcast", currentActivity, requestCode, alarmIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.Call("set", 0, triggerTime, pendingIntent);

        // Store the action to be executed when the alarm triggers
        AlarmReceiver.OnAlarmTriggered += new AlarmReceiver.AlarmAction(action);
    }
}

public class AlarmReceiver : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public delegate void AlarmAction();
    public static event AlarmAction OnAlarmTriggered;

    public AlarmReceiver() : base("android.content.BroadcastReceiver")
    {
    }

    public void onReceive(AndroidJavaObject context, AndroidJavaObject intent)
    {
        if (intent.Call<string>("getAction") == "Server_Managment_Background_Processes") // "YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION" is the unique identifier like the notification id in scqeduling notifications so a good value would be something like "Function Call 1" or something
        {
            if (OnAlarmTriggered != null)
            {
                OnAlarmTriggered.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is aprecitated

Comment: Just as a note, this isn't a safe way of doing singletons in unity, you'll want to do it in awake and only assign the instance if `instance != this && instance == null`, else you'll want to destroy the object. Currently you can have multiple or no instances quite easily

Comment: Yea i was just testing the script as i would usually refence an main gameobject that has master control scripts like this but for testing i just wanted to get it working so i could even see if it was a viable option